# FMDBMigrationManager crash

Tags: ios, crash, cocoapods, layer, fmdb

My application crashes soon after the launch with the error stack.

I had FMDB and FMDBMigrationManager as submodule which I replaced it with Cocoapods as one of the pods had dependency on both FMDB and FMDBManager.

```
LayerKit client v0.16.0 loaded
2015-09-14 10:08:27.793 MyApplication[52679:3399307] Error inserting batch: table schema_migrations already exists
2015-09-14 10:08:27.874 MyApplication[52679:3399307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to call designated initializer.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation           0x000000011111ac65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib          0x0000000110d81bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   MyApplication            0x000000010c107cc7 -[PodLayerKit_FMDBFileMigration SQL] + 0
    3   MyApplication            0x000000010c0947ab -[FMDBMigrationManager migrations] + 1515
    4   MyApplication            0x000000010c093aac -[FMDBMigrationManager pendingVersions] + 220
    5   MyApplication            0x000000010c0951cd -[FMDBMigrationManager migrateDatabaseToVersion:progress:error:] + 125
    6   MyApplication            0x000000010bb688af -[SQLiteDatabaseConnection openOrCreateDatabase:] + 479
    7   MyApplication            0x000000010bcb3aea -[SQLiteTableStore initWithSqliteDatabaseConnection:queryStringBuilder:databaseName:tableName:] + 330
    8   MyApplication            0x000000010b569ad7 __31-[PersistenceModule configure:]_block_invoke_2 + 279
    9   MyApplication            0x000000010c4a1b3c -[BSBlockProvider provide:injector:] + 124
    10  MyApplication            0x000000010c4a1765 -[BSSingleton provide:injector:] + 181
    11  MyApplication            0x000000010c49e442 -[BSInjectorImpl getInstance:withArgArray:] + 338
    12  MyApplication            0x000000010c49e26d -[BSInjectorImpl getInstance:withArgs:] + 701
    13  MyApplication            0x000000010c49df7e -[BSInjectorImpl getInstance:] + 94
    14  MyApplication            0x000000010b56991d __31-[PersistenceModule configure:]_block_invoke + 141
    15  MyApplication            0x000000010c4a1b3c -[BSBlockProvider provide:injector:] + 124
    16  MyApplication            0x000000010c4a1765 -[BSSingleton provide:injector:] + 181
    17  MyApplication            0x000000010c49e442 -[BSInjectorImpl getInstance:withArgArray:] + 338
    18  MyApplication            0x000000010c49e26d -[BSInjectorImpl getInstance:withArgs:] + 701
    19  MyApplication            0x000000010c49df7e -[BSInjectorImpl getInstance:] + 94
    20  MyApplication            0x000000010b6e1686 -[AppDelegate init] + 390
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010de9d87f UIApplicationMain + 1217
    22  MyApplication            0x000000010b5687f3 main + 451
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001119cd145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it?